# Between [ano-natsu-de-matteru] or [waiting-in-the-summer], which one should be the master tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

[*Ano Natsu de Matteru*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waiting_in_the_Summer) was licensed by Sentai Filmworks to be released in NA under the name *Waiting in the Summer*.

I flagged for synonym suggesting that [ano-natsu-de-matteru](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ano-natsu-de-matteru) should be used as master tag, and [waiting-in-the-summer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/waiting-in-the-summer) as synonym. The moderator handling my flag suggests that I open a meta discussion to sort this out (probably because it's not clear which one is better).

Which one should be the master tag?

Comment: If it is for master tag using Japanese version is more suitable, so for me [tag:ano-natsu-de-matteru] should be master tag

Answer (score 7):

I prefer [ano-natsu-de-matteru](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ano-natsu-de-matteru) over [waiting-in-the-summer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/waiting-in-the-summer), since the title *Waiting in the Summer* is rather generic in English. While the corresponding title is also generic in Japanese, the romaji title is not.

Comment: Ano Natsu de Matteru has about twice the google results and I've mostly seen it referred to with the Japanese title, so I'd say go with that - I think the opinion we decided on for master tags were the ones that were most popular (not necessarily decided by google searches)

Comment: Swapped the tags so that [ano-natsu-de-matteru] is the master.